# Should web3.currentProvider.send() return a promiEvent when called with async/await?

Tags: web3js, web3-providers

According to the [web3.js docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/callbacks-promises-events.html) I'd expect it shouldn't be necessary to use callbacks. When no callback is passed, promise-like "promiEvents" should be returned. Why is the ouput of the following example "result `undefined`"?

```
  try {
    const result = await web3.currentProvider.send({
      method: "eth_sendPrivateTransaction",
      params: [ signedTx ],
      jsonrpc: "2.0",
      id: new Date().getTime()
    });
    console.log('result', result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
```

It seems like there's an unresolved [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/2069) related to this. Is it still necessary to use callbacks with `web3.currentProvider.send()` in web3 version 1.3.3?

Edit: `WebsocketProvider` [for example declares](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/1.x/packages/web3-providers-ws/src/index.js#L304) `send(payload, callback)` as follows:

```
WebsocketProvider.prototype.send = function (payload, callback) {
    ...
};
```

What seems to be missing is a `send(payload)` function that takes just one argument and returns a Promise (or "promiEvent"?)

Comment: What is the send() function you are using? I don't see it in the documentation. send() can only be called on a contract method. Do you want to use sendTransaction()?.

Comment: It's the send function of the current provider. I've added WebsocketProvider as example.

Comment: Not all functions return PromiEvents. Some only return a regular Pormise, some return a PromiEvent. When they do return a PromiEvent, it's explicitly written in the doc (see this for instance https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction). The send() function you are calling directly on the provider is not even in the doc, so I would not assume that it should return a PromiEvent.

Comment: Thanks, I realize it's a design choice of each provider, if they want to follow that web3's promiEvent convention. Maybe there's an elegant way to extend providers to support async/await in the `send()` fuction. @Undead8, I would accept this as answer, if there's no more activity here.

Comment: I copied my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all functions return PromiEvents. Some only return a regular Promise, some return a PromiEvent. When they do return a PromiEvent, it's explicitly written in the doc (see [this](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction) for instance ).

The `send()` function you are calling directly on the provider is not even in the doc, so I would not assume that it should return a PromiEvent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `promisify` to transform the function into one that can be called with async/await. Something like this:

```
import util from "util";

const sendRpc = util.promisify((this.web3.currentProvider as IpcProvider).send)
    .bind(this.web3.currentProvider);

try {

    const response = await sendRpc({
        jsonrpc: "2.0",
        method: "admin_nodeInfo",
        params: [],
        id: (new Date()).getTime(),
    });
} catch(error) {
    ...
}
```

I'm using TypeScript in this example but the syntax should be similar for regular ES6.